# How can i send parameters to translation file in symfony2 validator engine?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, translation

the {{ limit }} variables will not be replaced for the length when i use the translations files.

My variable with the validation stuff

```
/**
 * The Username
 *
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.username.notBlank")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="user.username.notNull")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 2,
 *      max = 50,
 *      minMessage = "user.username.length.min",
 *      maxMessage = "user.username.length.max"
 * )
 * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string", name="username")
 */
private $username;
```

My translation file:

```
user:
username:
notBlank: Der Benutzername darf nicht leer sein.
notNull: Der Benutzername darf nicht leer sein.
length:
  min: Der Benutzername muss mindestens {{ limit }} Zeichen lang sein.
  min: Der Benutzername darf maximal {{ limit }} Zeichen lang sein.
```

After the translation i got the error

> "Der Benutzername muss mindestens {{ limit }} Zeichen lang sein."

instead of

> "Der Benutzername muss mindestens 2 Zeichen lang sein."

Comment: this may not about your issue but you have 2 min keyword in translation file. max key doesn't exist.

Comment: @LugiHaue
Idk what you mean with "2 min keywords", if you mean "{{ limit }}" then its correct..
{{ limit }} is for the min AND max value (see the docu => http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Length.html )

Comment: I mean max key doesn’t exist in your code.

Comment: @LugiHaue
Oh, yea....
But this is not the problem... i tested with the min key :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your version of Symfony?

Maybe a problem of indentation, try

```html
user:
  username:
     notBlank: Der Benutzername darf nicht leer sein.
     notNull: Der Benutzername darf nicht leer sein.
     length:
       min: Der Benutzername muss mindestens {{ limit }} Zeichen lang sein.
       max: Der Benutzername darf maximal {{ limit }} Zeichen lang sein.
```

You wrote 2 times "min"

or owerride translations validator

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already wrote that the 2 times "min" not the issue is.
I use silex 2.2 (symfony 3.3).